# Infomaniak Unmanaged Cloud Server increase partition size without data loss

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, partition, disk-volume

I recently asked Infomaniak to *increase* size of allocated (available) disk space from 100 to 250GB.

But after reboot, on Ubuntu (16.04 Server) when I run `df -h` I see my volume still at 100GB size.

So what to do to expand my volume **to new size** but **keeping data on it**.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself and want to share it with you.

> First of all, **backup all data**, before start this, we never know what could happen !

Step-by-step commands :

1) First you need to stop services depending on data of this volume, for me it was apache and mysql :

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

2) After we unmount the `/dev/vdb` volume :

```
sudo umount /dev/vdb
```

3) Now we check the filesystem with `fsck` command :

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/vdb
```

4) Let's resize it with `resize2fs` :

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/vdb
```

5) Now the volume has the good size, we can re-mount it :

```
sudo mount /dev/vdb /your/mount/point
```

6) Restart service if you stopped them on 1) :

```
sudo service mysql start
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: It worked great (in Infomaniak's Disk block system /vdb) Thank you having shared your solution, simple and efficient !
Even their support didin't direct me to that answer!
Kind regards

Comment: Well,  David became Goliath ;-( So, I decided to change hosting provider after this and other disappointments ! let's try alphosting ;-)